# using $GLOBALS['base_path']

Tags: uri

A quick one - is it ok to use this? I can't seem to get access to $base_url in my node which is set in my settings.php file.

Comment: Yes it is ok to use this one. In D7 there is base_path() function which return the same value. See here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/base_path/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not OK to use it directly. Always use [`base_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/base_path/7) function instead. There are two benefits:

1. You will not risk accidental change in the original variable, so you will not cause other modules to fail if you'll make a mistake.
2. If, for whatever reason, Drupal will change way it stores base path, your module will continue to work properly.